# Java Hibernate constant in sql-query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Below is the original content of a hibernate sql query I have:

```
<sql-query name="countryOfOrigin-limit-country-city-location">
<return alias="rb" class="RecentBooking"/>
    SELECT 
        bb.reserv_num as {rb.reservNum}, 
        bb.origin as {rb.countryOfOrigin}, 
        bb.pick_up_loc as {rb.locationId}, 
        bb.first_date as {rb.bookingDate}, 
        bb.pick_up_time as {rb.pickUpDate}, 
        bb.drop_off_time as {rb.dropOffDate},  
        bb.car_price as {rb.carPrice}, 
        bb.discount as {rb.discount}, 
        bb.exchange_rate as {rb.exchangeRate},
        SUBSTRING(a.internal_class,1,1)as {rb.carClass},
        a.car_type as {rb.carType}, 
        bb.vehicle_type as {rb.vehicleType}, 
        s.name as {rb.supplier}, 
        vv.country as {rb.country}, 
        vv.city as {rb.city}, 
        vv.location as {rb.location}, 
        bb.cur as {rb.currency}, 
        a.pics as {rb.carImage}
    FROM (SELECT * FROM b  WHERE first_date > DATE(NOW()-1)AS bb  
    JOIN a a ON a.id = bb.car_id
    JOIN d  d ON d.id = bb.pick_up_loc
    JOIN supplier s ON s.id = d.supplier_id
    JOIN v_location_trans vv ON vv.location_id = d.location_id
    AND vv.lang=33
    AND vv.country = :country
    AND vv.city = :city
    AND vv.location = :location
    AND bb.origin = :countryOfOrigin
    ORDER BY bb.id DESC
    LIMIT :limit
</sql-query>
```

The sql runs fast enough, but as you might have noticed there is a big, the NOW()-1 should be NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY.

I modified the nested select statement as follows:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM b WHERE first_date > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS bb
```

The fix works fine in terms of results, however the query slows down massively (pretty much almost instant up to a few seconds).

I believe this is because the DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) is being evaluated a large number of times (we have a very large data set). How would I go about seperating this calculation so that it only occurs once, without having to pass it in from java code like the country, city, limit, etc?

I have very little experience with hibernate or SQL, and I have tried seperating the calculation out into a variable before the select statement, which isnt allowed. I have also tried making small changes to the SQL query but I keep getting runtime errors, presumably due to invalid SQL.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new temp table `bb` in your query on the whole record.

I would suggest that you should filter out the result in creating the temp table.

for example if you put the AND clause while creating temp table

`AND bb.origin = :countryOfOrigin`

Like:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM b  WHERE first_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND origin = :countryOfOrigin)AS bb
```

Also you can put the limit it it as well.

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM b  WHERE first_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND origin = :countryOfOrigin LIMIT :limit)AS bb
```

**EDITED** -- New Answer.

I thing you do not need to change the `INTERVAL 1 DAY`, you stick to the previous query but replace the `1` with `86400000` which is equal to `INTERVAL 1 DAY` (24*60*60*1000)

new query would look like

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM b WHERE first_date > (NOW() - 86400000) 
               AND origin = :countryOfOrigin LIMIT :limit) AS bb
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I will bear these changes in mind. How would you recommend I put the - INTERVAL 1 DAY to speed things up? The query actually runs very fast with DATE(NOW()-1), it's just the INTERVAL business that is slowing it down immensely

Comment: you can use `NOW()-(24*60*60*1000)` But also convert it by date. Or you can use `(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY)` it will return u already `date`. so no conversion is required.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and there is no speed improvement. the math calculation is the same as using INTERVAL 1 DAY, and putting some of the conditionals into the first select doesnt affect speed. My original question asked if there was any way to seperate the calculation so it only runs once in the current sql query